# NestJS TCP Microservices deployment

Tags: deployment, tcp, nestjs, microservices, backend

Having a main back end gateway built on [Nest.JS](https://nestjs.com/), we did build a microservice  using @nestjs/microservices@9.0.0 package and hade him communicate with the main back end via TCP layer.

This is how we did define the microservice itself inside main.ts

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Transport, MicroserviceOptions } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(
    AppModule,
    {
      transport: Transport.TCP,
      options: {
        host: process.env.HOST || '',
        port: Number(process.env.PORT) || 3000,
        retryAttempts: 3,
        retryDelay: 1000
      }
    }
  );

  await app.listen();
}
bootstrap();
```

And this is how we did register the microservice inside a microservice.module.ts within `@Module({})`

```
    ClientsModule.register([
      {
        name: 'DNS_MICROSERVICE',
        transport: Transport.TCP,
        options: {
          host: process.env.DNS_API_BASEHOST || 'localhost',
          port: 3000
        }
      }
    ])
```

I think it is worth mentioning that we do use @MessagePattern() and .send(), in order to send messages between the applications. Locally, everything works fine.

Unfortunately, when deploying the microservice and sending the request via main back end to the deployed application, it simply timeouts after 30 seconds with no errors in addition to that.

The main back end and the microservice are deployed on separate servers, but, we did open a TCP port from the microservice server in order to make it able to communicate with the outside world. On top of that, we did check the Firewall, and it seems that there are no issues on that side either.

My questions are following - what is making it not work? how can we fix it in order to reached the deployed microservice application that uses TCP and is initiated as a microservice from our main back end?

We are using GCP and Dockerhub for deployment as far as I am concerned, but unfortunately I personally, do not have access to those.

First thing that I did think of, was checking if the connection can be open to the server itself. We did check if the port could be open via -nc and got the following result

```
ouruser@app:~$ nc -w1 -z -v ansible.our-application.fi 30000
Connection to ansible.our-application.fi (10.1.2.18) 30000 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
ouruser@app:~$ nc -w1 -z -v 182.24.48.244 30000
Connection to 182.24.48.244 30000 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

After numerous timeouts, I decided to send requests to not a single endpoint of our deployed microservice, but try reach out to other ones and did receive in return this

`[Nest] 10448  - 06/09/2023, 12:37:52 PM   ERROR [ClientTCP] Error: read ECONNRESET`

We do understand that ECONNRESET means the other side of the TCP conversation abruptly closed its end of the connection. The question still remains the same - why?

On top of that, we tried to deploy the microservice as a standalone application and make the request via simple HTTP requests, and it did work. If deployed as a separate Nest.JS application, the build does respond to requests and sends responses as we expected, with no timeouts. But unfortunately, this is not what we need.

Comment: Try to set `host` in your server's config to `0.0.0.0`